# Problems Updating content of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

As a newbie to Javascript, I don't find the language easy. The code below fades between two divs. During the fade, I would like to change the contents of each div. While I can successfully update CSS parameters, I have been unable to update the content. Perhaps somebody can help:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <style type='text/css' media='screen, print'>
    #cycler {
      position: relative;
    }
    #cycler div {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      background-color: white
    }
    #cycler div p {
      font-size: 60px;
      color: black;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #cycler div.active {
      z-index: 3
    }
    #cycler img {
      display: block
    }
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function() {
      setInterval('divCycler()', 3000);
    });

    function divCycler(e) {
      var $active = $('#cycler .active');
      var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler div:first');
      $next.css('z-index', 2);
      $active.fadeOut(1500, function() {
        $active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass('active');
        $active.innerHTML = "New HTML Text"; // This Line is not working !!!!!!!!!!!
        $active.css('background-color', 'red');
        $next.css('z-index', 3).addClass('active');
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div id='cycler'>
      <div id='div1' class='active'>
        <p>Test Message 1</p>
      </div>
      <div id='div2'>
        <p>Test Message 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have shown the complete HTML page including all the Javascript; there is no other code to this. Any help on the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: avoid `eval` strings. Change `setInterval('divCycler()', 3000);` to `setInterval(divCycler, 3000);`

Comment: Please consider adding some feedback to the existing answers and if one helped you check the green mark to accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
$active.innerHTML = "New HTML Text"; // This Line is not working !!!!!!!!!!!
```

is because `$active` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element, to solve your problem use:

```
$active[0].innerHTML = "New HTML Text";
```

or, with jQuery itself:

```
$active.html("New HTML Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()` instead of `innerHTML`

```
        $active.html("New HTML Text"); // This Line is not working
```

[jQuery Documentation: html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)